# FancyBox iFrame - Link in iFrame to close FancyBox and open in original parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have FancyBox link that opens a FancyBox (lightbox) iFrame php page.  This php page has links on it and I want any of the links when clicked to close the FancyBox Lightbox and open the link in the original parent window... Here is my code so far...

```
   <a class="fancyimg" data-fancybox-type="iframe" onClick="$.fn.fancybox.close();" href="remote.php" >Launch Remote Control</a>

{literal}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(".fancyimg").fancybox({
 'width'        : '30%',
 'height'       : '92%',
 'autoScale'        : false, 
 'type'         : 'iframe',
 'overlayShow'   : false,
 'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
 'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
});


</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you could only do that if you have control over the opened page AND both are within the same domain. BYW, the fancybox API options in your code are for v1.3.4 and not compatibles with v2.x

Comment: I have control over the opened page and both are on the same domain, can you give me an example of how I can set this up to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to set an `onclick` *attribute* on each link of the *iframed* page (*remote.php*) that calls a *function* in the `parent` page and passes their `href` as parameter.

You could do this on-the-fly within the fancybox `afterShow` callback, so no need to hard-code the *attribute* in the *iframed* page.

Then the function in the *parent* page should close fancybox using the `$.fancybox.close()` method and reload the page with the URL passed from the *iframed* page.

The code that goes in the *parent* page :

```
// this function gets the href of the clicked link in the iframed page
// then closes fancybox
// then reloads the current page with the new href
function closeFancybox(href){
  jQuery.fancybox.close();
  window.location.href = href;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        afterShow : function () {
            // set the onclick attribute on each link of the iframed page
            // then passes the corresponding href to the parent page function
            $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("a").attr("onclick", "parent.closeFancybox(this.href)");
        },
        // other API options
    })
}); // ready
```

See **[DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/closeIframeClickLinks_02dec14.html)** at *picssel.com* and feel free to explore the source code.

---

Another (cleaner) option, without setting an `onclick` *attribute*, is to bind the `click` *event* directly within the `afterShow` callback like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        afterShow : function () {
            // bind a click event on each link of the iframed page
            // then call the closeFancybox and pass the corresponding href
            $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("a").on("click", function () {
                closeFancybox(this.href);
            });
        }
    })
}); // ready
```

See alternative **[DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/closeIframeClickLinks_II_02dec14.html)**

**IMPORTANT**: Both solutions are subject to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) so it's assumed both pages belong to the same domain.

**NOTE** : this is for fancybox v2.x